# Geometric decomposition of covariant derivative operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading the article *Discrete Connection and Covariant Derivative for Vector Field Analysis and Design*, but I got stuck on a seemingly easy statement.

> Let $M$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold with a **metric
> connection** $\nabla$. Let $I$ be the identity matrix,
> $$J =
>  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } F =
>  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} 
> $$ Then for a vector
> field $u$, the matrix representation of $\nabla u$ can be rearranged
> into four geometrically relevant terms:
> $$ \nabla u = 
>  \frac{1}{2}(I\nabla \cdot u + J \nabla\times u + F\nabla \cdot (Fu) +
>  JF \nabla \times (Fu) ) $$
> where $\nabla \cdot$ is the divergence operator and $\nabla \times$ is the curl operator.

In the article, the local basis is omitted. I'm not sure how to read the above formula, and the followings are my understanding.

I view $\nabla u$ as a $(1,1)$-type tensor. The $(1,1)$-entry in the matrix representation is $$ \nabla u(\partial x_i,dx^1) = dx^1 (\nabla_{\partial x_1} u) = \frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x_1} + u^1 \Gamma^1_{11} + u^2 \Gamma^1_{12}$$
where $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$ is the Christoffel symbol, defined by $\nabla_{\partial x_i} \partial x_j = \Gamma_{ij}^k \partial x_k$.

However, on the RHS, the divergence operator is defined without involving Christoffel symbols and they are not completely determined the metric structure. Even if we assume the connection is Levi-Civita, expressing $$ \nabla \cdot u = tr \circ \nabla u = \frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x^1} + u^1 \Gamma^1_{11} + u^2 \Gamma^1_{12} + \frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2} + u^1 \Gamma^2_{21} + u^2 \Gamma^2_{22}, $$
the $(1,1)$-entry reads $$ \frac{\partial u^1}{\partial x^1} + u^1 \Gamma^1_{11} + u^1 \Gamma^2_{21}, $$
which is not equal to the $(1,1)$-entry on the LHS.

It seems that I misunderstood something. Any help is appreciated.